# Use double quote in sql querys c#

Tags: c#, sql-server, string

I'm developing an application that executes queries in a Sqlserver database. One of these queries needs double quotes.

```
select ....soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"...from...where...
```

I put the query in a string type variable. I use inverted bar to scape to scape the double quote and define them in the string.
But when I execute my app, I get a error when my app execute this query.

This is the error message:

```
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'declare'.

'soapenv' is not a recognized CURSOR option.
```

How could define my query?

This is my query:

```
SELECT XMLFile.value('declare namespace   soapenv=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\";declare namespace cus=\"http://nestle-eai/Schemas/esb/Customer\";declare namespace inf=\"http://nestle-eai/Schemas/esb/Infrastructure\";declare namespace ars=\"http://nestle-eai/Schemas/ar/arService\";(soapenv:Envelope/soapenv:Body/ars:setCustomerIn/parameters/cus:customer/cus:VeevaId)[1]','VARCHAR(20)') FROM dbo.VEEVA_XML
```

Thanks in advance!
Regards

Comment: It would really help if you could show some actual code. Generally you should separate your values from the SQL itself, using parameterized SQL - at which point a lot of this goes away. We really don't have enough context to help you at the moment.

Comment: Things will work a lot more easily if you use single-quotes; and if the value comes from the application and isn't hard-coded and never-changing: use a parameter instead. It would be much easier to help with a more realistic/complete code example.

Comment: a) `"` is not a string delimiter in MS SQL. b) Your example code doesn't use `declare`.

Comment: oh please please tell me you aren't trying to build soap 
xml inside sql server...

Comment: I have wrotten the complete query in my original post. I have tried with diferents solutions, but i don't get success. I have used inverted bar, @symbol, replace methods but i cant get the solution. Internally, C# always put the inverter bar and this doens't work in the sqlserver.

C# isn't Java, I can't define a string with simple quotes. It's reserved to char type.

Comment: And yes, Im trying to build soap xml inside sqlserver. I got to create the xml, now im trying to catch a external soap xml and imported to my database

Comment: It wasn't a problem with the C# strings. It was a problem with the sqlserver options. I have had to define this sentences before to execute my query in my app:

    SET NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT OFF
 
    SET ANSI_NULLS, ANSI_PADDING, ANSI_WARNINGS, ARITHABORT, CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL, QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON

And now, It works correctly!

Answer (score 0):

sql query should be like this (look at ["]):

```
SELECT XMLFile.value('declare namespace soapenv="http://schemas..."; ... ','VARCHAR(20)') FROM ...
```

in c#, same as in java it will be:

```
String qry = "SELECT XMLFile.value('declare namespace soapenv=\"http://schemas...\"; ... ','VARCHAR(20)') FROM ...";
```

here [\"] encodes ["].